# Why the character in my 2D game is not moving?

Tags: java, swing, 2d-games

My program has 3 java files, namely Frame, Dude(which contains the character) and Board(which implements the actionListener). My program is not throwing any error and the images(background and character) are rendering good. But the character is not moving forward.

---

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame= new JFrame("2D Game");
        frame.add(new Board());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1200, 600);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Dude {
    int x, dx, y;
    Image still;

    public Dude(){
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("/home/amitabh/Pictures/man1.jpg");
        still= i.getImage();
        x=10;
        y=172;
        }

    public void move(){
        x=x+dx;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public Image getImage(){
        return still;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int key= e.getKeyCode();

        if(key== KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
        dx= -1;

        if(key== KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
        dx= 1;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        int key= e.getKeyCode();

        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
        dx=0;

        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
        dx=0;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    Image img;
    Timer time;
    Dude p;

    public Board(){
        p= new Dude();
        addKeyListener(new AL());
        setFocusable(true);
        ImageIcon i= new ImageIcon("/home/amitabh/Pictures/game1.png");
        img= i.getImage();
        time= new Timer(5,this);
        time.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        p.move();
        repaint();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d= (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.drawImage(img, 0,0, null);
        g2d.drawImage(p.getImage(), p.getX(), p.getY(), null);
    }

    public class AL extends KeyAdapter{
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            p.keyReleased(e);
        }
        public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            p.keyPressed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `KeyListener` is be called?

Comment: thats the exact program...if I missed it ...pls help@MadProgrammer

Comment: yeah the keylistener is in the Board class constructor@MadProgrammer

Comment: You need to start learning to debug, `KeyListener` is fickel and sometimes won't trigger events, how ever, in your case, that's not the primary problem

Comment: how to learn debugging...any inputs that can help me@MadProgrammer

Comment: Use `System.out.println` to print messages to the console at various points in your code to verify.  If you're using of the Java IDE's they have the capabilities to allow you to place breakpoints in the code (and when in debug mode) inspect the state of the variables and allow you to step through your code, it's a bit of black magic, but a lot of fun to

Answer (score 2):

Start by talking a very close look at:

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
```

Does that look funny to you?

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT); // <--- What's the ; doing here?
```

Change it to be more like...

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
    dx = 0;
}
```

And, yes, this is why you're encouraged to use `{ ... }`

Next, take a closer look at...

```
public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
```

See anything wrong there?  Why does it start with an uppercase `K`, that's not the correct method signature

Change to something more like...

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    p.keyReleased(e);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    p.keyPressed(e);
}
```

Yes, this is why you're encouraged to use `@Override` ;)

And finally change your `paint` method to `paintComponent`

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
```

You are encouraged to override `paintComponent` when performing custom painting, it tends to cause less issues

I'd also encorage you to have a look at the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and favour it over `KeyListener` as it provides better control of the focus level required to trigger the key events

I'd also encourage your to override `getPreferredSize` of the `Board` and return your preferred size from there, rather then setting the frame's size.  The frame size includes the frame's decorations, so you content is smaller then the frame size

Comment: you are god@MadProgrammer

Comment: No, I just don't have a life ;)

Comment: Gods don't have a life... (1+ for a nice answer) :)